# Sending POST JSON data using HttpURLConnection and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to send some JSON data (if its a problem it may be a normal string) but it's not working at all. 
When I add getResponseCode it sends POST with empty body to the server but the headers are set (Content-Type - application/json). I tried on many different ways but there is always empty body. Can someone look at it? I feel like I am missing something important...

```
//when button is tapped:
final String url = "http://postcatcher.in/catchers/";
new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);


public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            // conn.getResponseCode

            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("name", "Andrew");
            jsonParam.put("code", "5412274");

            OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.write(jsonParam.toString());
            os.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

The thing is that when I am using that conn.getResponse Code I'm sure that there is connection with server but the body is empty. 
When i delete it, the POST message are not sending at all (seems that it is not working)

Comment: `When I add getResponseCode`. Please put that on the right place in your code. You may comment it.

Answer (score 0):

On that place you have not send anything yet so you cannot expect a response. You will have an IOException for that then. Log it and look in the logcat. If you want to know the response you should put it after you have send all. So after os.flush(). But you are not reading the response. The webserver will send something back isn't it? You are not reading that from conn.getInputStream(). Read it otherwise you will never know what the catcher answers.